# Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF while executing composer network install command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i'm trying to connect multi org using hyperledger fabric ( using below link ) : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

at step no: 11,12 - ( **composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 --archiveFile trade-network.bna** ) , i'm getting error like

vb:~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-samples/first-network$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 --archiveFile trade-network.bna

**✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: EOF
Command failed**

docker ps o/p is: [docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TizsZ.png)

**docker version :** 18.09.0

**composer version:** v0.20.4

Comment: Could you please add the error text messages instead of putting pictures? Thanks!

Comment: updated error message instead of image

Comment: From the docker ps output, it looks like the Fabric is running OK, and has started the 3 chaincode containers for "mycc" - so a failure to connect to it suggests errors in the connection.json, or some other networking issue.  What do you have in the URL field for the Peers?

Comment: url for peer0.org1 : grpc://localhost:7051, peer1.org1:grpc://localhost:8051, peer0.org2: grpc://localhost:9051, peer1.org2: grpc://localhost:10051

Comment: for the multi-org tutorial these urls don't look correct. The fabric will be running with TLS enabled, so those urls should start with `grpcs://` (ie an 's' after 'grpc')

Comment: if i replace grpc with grpcs also, i'm getting same error